# Download large data to Excel

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, excel, openxml

I have about 3 million rows in SqlDataReader (~500Mb).
How can I deliver this data to client Excel?  (excel has limitation 1048K rows per sheet)

Tried to use ClosedXml. But more than 100K per sheet I didn't manage to create. Always get OutOfMemoryException when do InsertData. 
Os - Win 32x

Don't suggest - txt download. Already done. Now need Excel with either dividing data by sheets or files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you reading and moving one row at a time into the Excel sheet, or loading up all 500mb of data at once and trying to dump it into the Excel sheet? For the OutOfMemoryException, I would make sure you're moving rows directly from the SqlDataReader (one row, or as few rows as possible, at a time) into some sort of buffered stream writer (that periodically flushes) for the Excel sheet (if such a thing exists). You should avoid using too much memory at once then.

Comment: Actually problem with SaveAs in ClosedXml. Whenever I try to save about 100K rows it raise an error. With 50K rows no problem. But in the same time I cannot to write directly to output response stream as I did for text files, because ClosedXml doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a commercial product. I suggest SoftArtisans Officewriter. You can [download an eval here](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-free-evaluation.aspx)

With OfficeWriter you can use [ExcelTemplate's BindData](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW8/ExcelTemplate.BindData%28System.Data.IDataReader,+String,+DataBindingProperties%29) in conjunction with the [continue modifier](http://wiki.softartisans.com/display/EW70/Creating+Data+Markers#CreatingDataMarkers-modifiers)

What this boils down to is < 10 lines of code an a couple of placeholders in a template file.It is very easy to implement and will allow you to seamlessly have your data go on to the next worksheet.

Disclaimer: I work for SoftArtisans the makers of OfficeWriter

Answer (score 0):

How this data will be used?
If they'll end in some sort of pivot table you might consider Powerpivot as well.

It's able to manage way more than 3 million rows and it's free unless you need to publish it into a Sharepoint server.

Comment: This more like a question than an answer

Comment: Forgot to say. Users are Excel 2007. So PowerPivot is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Friend tried to import the data and then open with EXCEL? I've seen someone do it and it worked most do not know if it will work now with updates and integrity constraints that programmers put more tries, it does not work another dieia would do the following, you already have the commands in sql table and goes to print is easier for you to find everything there you will gradually upgrading it in execl

Answer (score 0):

3 million rows, 1 million rows per sheet? loop the data and load it into each sheet, or write some queries to split the first table into 3 smaller ones and load each new table in to a sheet. First will be dog slow but easy, second will be harder by faster.

Comment: Already. I use SqlDataReader with loop to part sheets by 100K rows. But even this data cannot be saved

Comment: How are you loading the data into Excel? Try to do it all at once, not row by row. Load a million (or less) rows in to a array, then send the whole array to the worksheet.

Comment: I do like you said. But taking into account that I must save file either to MemoryStream or disk I get OutOfMemoryException always.

Comment: Out of memory errors are normally to do with the undo stack filling up,  so I can't understand when you can't save the file to disk.  What code are you using to write the data?